# Why multi_usrp does not support multiple B210 radios?

Tags: usrp

Why only some of the radios can be used by multi_usrp? Is it connected with the B210 hardware or UHD API is not developed?

Answer (score 0):

There's no specific reason, it's simply not implemented.

Comment: and things implemented are simply implemented. No reason. Life is simple.

Comment: Well the truth is that there's technical reasons that e.g. multiple N210 are more sensible to have in a single `multi_usrp` than B210s, but the fact that this is not implemented is a decision made by Ettus back in the day; @IvanPenchevIvanov . So Life isn't quite that simple.